# React - Can't style the active state of a react router navlink with css modules

Tags: css, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

#### Goal

I'm trying to apply styles to the active route in a sidebar using css modules, however i wanna keep the base styles (assigning 2 classes)

I've tried this code

```
   <NavLink
      to={path}
      className={`
       ${classes.nav_link} ${({ isActive }) =>
        isActive ? classes.active : classes.nav_link}
        }
      `}
    >
```

But it compiles to
[A snapshot of the css compiled code in devtools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EfLi.png)

I'm using *CSS modules*, *React Router V6*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood your query correctly, then you got to use ternary operator properly (something like below as per your requirement):

```
<NavLink
  to={path}
   className={({ isActive }) =>
    isActive ? classes.active : classes.nav_link
  }
>
```

Comment: That's worked perfectly, i had to apply the same base styles for both classes then target (active) with spcial styles. tysm brother

Answer (score 0):

The following solution works perfectly after upgrading to React Router v6:

```
import s from "./Navbar.module.css";

<div className={s.item}>
    <NavLink to="/profile" className={(navData) => navData.isActive ? s.active : ""}>Profile</NavLink>
</div>
```

And the navbar.module.css file is:

```
.item a {
    color: white;
}

.item a.active {
    color: gold;
}
```