# react-router NavLink issue

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-router

This question has been asked many times and I looked and tried many solutions.
I'm using `NavLink` from `react-router-dom` and I want to toggle the `className` active to mark the link clicked here is the code:

```
import React from 'react'
import styles from './NavBar.module.css'
import logo from '../assets/logos/icon-left-font-monochrome-white.svg'
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'

export default function NavBar() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.nav_contrainer}>
      <img className={styles.img} src={logo} alt='logo groupomania avec typo blanc' />
      <nav className={styles.nav}>
        <NavLink to='/home' exact='true' className={(navData) => (navData.isActive ? 'active' : 'none')} style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>
          <li>Home</li>
        </NavLink>

        <NavLink to='/articlebuilder' className={(navData) => (navData.isActive ? 'active' : 'none')} style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>
          <li>Écrire un article</li>
        </NavLink>

        <NavLink to='/profile' className={(navData) => (navData.isActive ? 'active' : 'none')} style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>
          <li>Profile</li>
        </NavLink>
      </nav>
    </div>
  )
}
```

This code has a solution from an other post, how ever it's not working for me...
I tried the `exact='true'` in all links but it still doesn't work.

Here is the code where the path are linked

```
<div className='App'>
  <Routes>
    <Route path='/' exact={true} element={<HomePage />} />
    <Route path='/landingpage' exact={true} element={<LandingPage />} />
    <Route path='/home' exact={true} element={<HomePage />} />
    <Route path='/profile' exact={true} element={<Profile />} />
    <Route path='/articlebuilder' exact={true} element={<ArticleBuilder />} />
    <Route path='/signup' exact={true} element={<Signup />} />
    <Route path='/signin' exact={true} element={<Signin />} />
  </Routes>
</div>
```

this is the css file:

```
.nav_contrainer {
  background-color: #ffac99;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0em 0em 0em 1em;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  position: sticky;
}

nav a {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  color: white;
  transition: all ease-in-out 350ms;
  padding: 10px;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #870e07;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav_contrainer img {
  width: 15%;
  height: 15%;
}

.active {
  color: #870e07;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Have I missed something?

Comment: What exactly is the issue? What isn't working? FYI, there's no `exact` prop for routes or links in RRDv6, but if there were it likely wouldn't be a string literal.

Comment: the class isActive is shown in the browser but is not doing anything, while i set it to display an other color

Comment: Where are you setting it to another color. BTW, the `NavLink` components already use an `active` class by default, you only need to use the `className` function if you want to provide different class names.

Comment: i am setting it inside the NavBar.module.css that i import. so you mean i could go inside my css file and just declare the active class and use it?

Comment: Yes, that is very likely. Can you include your CSS code in your question? It would be considered part of a [minimal, complete, and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: ok, i tried naming it active withou the dot but still nothing

Comment: Does this solve you question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71979254/react-cant-style-the-active-state-of-a-react-router-navlink-with-css-modules/71979401#71979401

Comment: NavLink when pressed should automatically add .active class. Make sure to have the .active class included and problem should be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your class needs to be the `active` class from the `NavBar` CSS module.

```
function NavBar() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.nav_contrainer}>
      <img className={styles.img} src={logo} alt='logo groupomania avec typo blanc' />
      <nav className={styles.nav}>
        <NavLink
          to="/home"
          className={(navData) => (navData.isActive ? styles.active : "none")}
          style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}
        >
          <li>Home</li>
        </NavLink>

        <NavLink
          to="/articlebuilder"
          className={(navData) => (navData.isActive ? styles.active : "none")}
          style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}
        >
          <li>Écrire un article</li>
        </NavLink>

        <NavLink
          to="/profile"
          className={(navData) => (navData.isActive ? styles.active : "none")}
          style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}
        >
          <li>Profile</li>
        </NavLink>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit react-router-navlink-issue]

[image]